# Which event fires when something dragged onto an input?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, rich-internet-application

I have a text input.

I drag the URL from a browser window into the text field. (Click hold on the URL bar, drag, let go of click in the text field).

Which event fires in this case?  Listening on `paste` ain't doing it.  Is this the same for every browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get an HTML5 `input` event in all browsers except IE<9, in which you can use the `propertychange` event instead.

Comment: i am using evt.target.value to get the value of the input -- do you know if that will work cross browsers?

Comment: @hvgotcodes: You'll need `window.event.srcElement.value` instead in IE <= 8, and the `propertychange` event doesn't bubble, so you'll need to attach your listener directly to the input you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

`paste` is the event that should work - what browser ?

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/VdUqx/1/  <- works for me in Chrome

Comment: yeah paste, and mouseup fire.  I was setting up my listener incorrectly.  Btw, your example is not working for me...

Comment: @hvgotcodes updated the way the event is attached - should work in all browsers now ...

Comment: hmm still not working.  I'm running the code in chrome, but can drag from the URL bar of any browser/window

Comment: @hvgotcodes Yes your right - not working for drag / drop - but working for paste ... not sure there is an event (other than mouseup) that will capture this event ...

Comment: @hvgotcodes here is an alternative way of doing it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021171/catch-image-dragged-into-a-text-field-in-javascript you could check for the `http` at the start ?